# MySQL 5.7 connection issue using ODBC 3.51 32 driver

Tags: mysql, 32-bit, odbc

I'm facing a really strange problem. I have the following configuration:

1. Ubuntu host with MySQL 5.7.25 Community edition running on it
2. Windows 10 guest VM with ODBC 32 bit driver 3.51
3. ssl tunnel from VM mapping the port 3306 from host to guest
4. DBA user 'admin'@'localhost', which has all the privileges
5. DB user 'mydb_user'@'localhost', which has all privileges only to mydb schema

I can connect to mydb using mysql workbench or command line from the guest VM without any issue as admin or mydb_user.

However, when I'm trying to configure DSN using MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver, only admin account connects successfully. The mydb_user fails to connect with the message "Access denied for user 'mydb_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)".

When I check the mysql logs it also shows 'Access denied' for this user. Even when I'm adding DBA grants to 'mydb_user' it doesn't help. Seems like something is different for 'admin' vs 'mydb_user' but I can't figure out what. Any hint would be much appreciated.

UPDATE. Interesting that only 32 bit driver has this issue. When I try to connect via MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver 64 bit, all users are connecting without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue was in the ODBC driver version. Version 3.51 32 bit does not work with MySQL 5.7. 
After updating to version MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver all is working with no issues.